# Understanding Bluetooth profiles

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to get my hands dirty on understanding Bluetooth (BT) for building a BT based speaker. When i read through Google on selecting the device, i came across CSR, TI and few more of them. After some research and talking to ppl, they suggested to go with TI (CC256x series). Few questions i have here are:

1. Can the same TI chip be used as Speaker, BT headset?
2. Can both SPP profiles and audio profiles co-exist together?
3. I am not sure as a application developer, i should know about BT firmware but wanted to get some insight on how BT works. Any good books?

Sorry for asking basic question here

-Prashanth

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes! Audio transfer requires a high data rate which means you have to use a chip that supports bluetooth classic and not low energy (ble). The CC256x offers both a bluetooth classic and a dual bluetooth (classic + low energy) version, both will work.
2. Yes! SPP and audio profiles are implemented on different streams and it is normal for them to co-exist.
3. Good books on bluetooth classic are hard to come by, one of the best places to start is the Apple developer documentation (linked down below). The developer area of bluetooth.org is also a good place to start.
   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Intro/BT_Intro.html

   https://developer.bluetooth.org/